# Ruby on Rails Flash[:notice] not working after deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, heroku

I have an app that has had working flashes while hosted locally, but after deploying to heroku they no longer work.

Here is my controller:

```
def create
@query = Query.new(params[:query])

respond_to do |format|
  if @query.save
    QueryMailer.new_query_email(@query).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to @query, notice: 'Query was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @query, status: :created, location: @query }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @query.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

And the view:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
<div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, I recommend checking on heroku that your deliver code earlier works first, that the mail was delivered, and also that the query was saved.

Comment: the mail goes out and the query is saved without a problem

Answer (score -1):

Please use this:

```
flash.now[:notice]
```

and also check the notice class is correct in html.

Comment: Tried   <% if flash.now[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash.now[:notice] %></div>
  <% end %> did not work either.